# Unable to match csrf-token in Lua

Tags: regex, lua

Gone around the houses on this one tonight. All I want to do is pull out the csrf-token in the following script however it returns `nil`

```
local html = '<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" /><meta content="ndcZ+Vp8MuM/hF6LizdrvJqgcRh22zF8w/DnIX0DvR0=" name="csrf-token" />'

local csrf_token = string.match(html, 'content="(.*)" name="csrf-token"')
```

If I modify the script and take off the "-token" part it matches *something*, but not the right thing of course.

I know it is the hyphen because if I modify the string to be "csrftoken" and the match it finds works as expected.

I attempted to escape the - like so `\-` but that threw an error...

elp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The `-` does need to be escaped, but Lua uses `%` instead of `\`.
2. Further, the reason why you get something odd is due to the fact the `.` can match anything, including across tags (or attributes) and tries to take as much as possible (since the engine will return the left-most possible match, ungreedy quantifiers wouldn't help either). What you should do is restrict the allowed characters, so that the captured thing cannot go outside of the attribute quotes - like `[^"]` (any character except quotes):

Taking all of that together:

```
local csrf_token = string.match(html, 'content="([^"]*)" name="csrf%-token"')
```

In any case, [you shouldn't actually be matching HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Ah ha! It was the % escaping I was needing! I now have another problem, which is that I'm using regex for matching HTML but as this is a throw away loadimpact test, I can cope with that.

Comment: @johnwards yeah, probably... I also don't know about an established DOM parser in Lua...

Comment: @m.buettner you probably wanted to put in a different link at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
name="csrf-token'"
```

You have an extra apostrophe at the end of this line.

I would also escape " = and the hyphen, though this may not be necessary for all these characters.

Comment: Although, I hope that this is for a legitimate purpose?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my example.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing load testing for a rails app with loadimpact.com :)

Comment: Also, I've attempted to escape the - with a \ but that throws an error on http://trylua.org/ (But not on loadimpact.com, it just doesn't match)